# How do I make the margins of a webpage shrink on horizontal window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the [Adirondack](https://adirondack-demo.squarespace.com/) template from Squarespace, there's a super crazy responsive feature where if you resize the window horizontally, the "margins" of the page start shrinking until it just kinda locks onto the main content of the page. I included a GIF of what I'm trying to articulate below.

How could I go about replicating that effect? All my attempts have just resulted in the *entire page* shrinking to scale instead of just the margins. (In my attempt, I styled the main content of the div to have margins from the left and right to replicate the kind of look in this template.)

[image: animated GIF of margin shrinking effect]

Comment: I wouldn't say that was achieved with margins, looks more to me like a central div with a set width/max-width applied. The rest just being grey background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this without using margins or media queries. Just use `max-width` on the content, i.e.

```
.content {
  // Make it as wide as possible…
  width: 100%;
  // … but only up to 250px
  max-width: 250px;

  // Center horizontally within parent
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Example:

```js
function updateWidth() {
  const slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
  document.querySelector(".parent").style.width = `${slider.value}%`;
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
}

.parent {
  background-color: #cecece;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
Use the slider to simulate resizing:

<input type="range" value="100" min="0" max="100" oninput="updateWidth()" class="slider" />

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted for writing out so nicely and concisely what I said above :D

Answer (score 0):

I normally center the main content div using `margin-left: 50%` and  `transform: translateX(-50%)`. Just make sure to use the various cross-browser rules when using transform. 
After that just set the divs width and max-width. See below or [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/36hukq5t/10/)

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-centered-div {
  color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1180px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-centered-div">
    Some content for my div. Some content for my div. Some content for my div. Some content for my div. Some content for my div. Some content for my div. Some content for my div. Some content for my div. Some content for my div. Some content for my div. Some
    content for my div. Some content for my div. Some content for my div. Some content for my div. Some content for my div. Some content for my div.
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```